# Java & gradle -> include only specific package from library

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-data

I've got a multi-modular java app built with spring and gradle, and I'm adding pagination and sorting feature. Basically, I need some models for sorting, pagination, pageable DTO's. 
Spring data already has an awesome package org.springframework.data.domain shipped within spring-data-commons jar - it contains everything, plus these models are used in spring data itself

However, in this jar there also are 17 more packages which I don't need. I don't want my web layer to know anything about some CrudRepository interface even in classpath - only about the sorting and pagination dtos.

So, is there any way to create some 'spring-data-domain-models' module that will have spring-data-commons as dependency, do some magic in build cycle and will only give access to one package to the outer world?

Comment: Component/Package scan is what you need I think - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning AND https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Comment: I don't need beans. This is not about beans, actually, this is about classpath dependencies